# Mathematica SE (human) language survey - Poll Closed

Tags: discussion

### Thanks a lot to all the users who took the time to answer the poll!

I was curious about the site users' distribution of native (and other known) languages.

I made a poll using SurveyMonkey (now closed). I hope you find the results interesting.

Comment: The results will be publicly available, of course

Comment: Google chrome: "This page is in Spanish, would you like to translate it"? I clicked no and half expected it would automatically check the Spanish box for me :P.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom The stup*d poll site decided the language for me and didn't let me change it. The only remaining text in Spanish is the "submit" button label, though.

Comment: The add looks fine to me, except for the modern-style text font. The thin strokes get lost in the background. Recommend an Egyptian (slab-serif) font to make the text more legible.

Comment: @m_goldberg  Thanks! I don't have your suggested font at hand, but used a bolder one. Please check it now.

Comment: It's much easier to read now. I question the capitalization of "Language" and "Survey".

Comment: @m_goldberg That's because it's a [modern ad](http://www.cartype.com/pics/2637/small/toyota_corona_sedan_ad_2_67.jpg)

Comment: Then it should have "Do We Speak" not "do we speak" to be consistent.

Comment: Will the _Mathematica StackExchange username_ be publicly available, too?

Comment: @xzczd Only if we vote here to do so (and nobody opposes). You can leave it blank, of course.

Comment: @xzczd If you filled it and had second thoughts just drop me a line and I'll wipe it.

Comment: I myself won't mind if it's published if I have filled it :)

Comment: Well, I missed the native languages like C, Python and similar...

Comment: @IstvánZachar That's going to be included in the next poll http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/14111680#14111680

Comment: Interesting poll! But options include Volapük but not Mandinka? Impressive selection anyway.

Comment: @OleksandrR. We already discovered a Latin and a Wolof speaker (or perhaps is the same person?). I got the list from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_languages. I used the shortest one (List of ISO 639-1 codes) because the full list of known languages seemed _a bit_ too large

Comment: Waitwaitwait! The poll asks: "What languages are you able to **read**?" I can read Latin, but I definitely cannot speak it. I never asked for a beer in Latin. Perhaps the question should be better specified? And one more thing: I've realized that you used "magyar nyelv" in the ad image associated with the poll. Actually, "magyar" is perfectly enough, as if it is not spelled with a capital M it is an adjective (means folk and language as well). "nyelv" means language, can be omitted.

Comment: @IstvánZachar The ad wording is applied marketing 101 :). It's OK to answer "Latin" if you've read Commentarii de bello Gallico. Regarding your observation on the language naming system, I've used **ISO 639-1**. Not that I like it very much (I disagree on my own first language naming there, for example), but it's at least -I thought- something nobody could blame me about :D -

Comment: I like the idea but I don't understand the purpose of such a poll :D Is it purely recreational?

Comment: @Öskå Ask Google what are they going to do with all that info :). Yeah, seriously, I'm just curious and found (for example) much more German, French and Spanish "speakers" than I expected. And I think this curiosity is shared among the community.

Comment: @Öskå Be patient. I'm updating it manually :) Look now

Comment: Ooooh, I thought it was somehow returning a list that you used with MMA. My bad :)

Comment: "magyar nyelv" does indeed sound silly.  It's like saying "the English language" in English.

Comment: @Szabolcs Do you see a "magyar nyelv" entry? Because I don't![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/BwpaK.png)

Comment: @belisarius perhaps a similar poll of latitude/longitude (or timezones derivable from) of user (with optional identification as this poll)...interesting wrt answering times and language correlations...

Comment: @ubpdqn See the new answer

Comment: When is the programming language survey coming? :-)  For that I'm more interested in what people use than in what people know.

Comment: @Szabolcs Why don't start a thread on meta to propose (and vote on) interesting questions to be included in the next poll?

Comment: @belisarius agree with thread on poll suggestions

Answer (score 9):

**Results so far (95 users):**
[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

```
{{"Bulgarian", 1}, {"Greek. Modern", 1}, {"Igbo", 1}, {"Japanese", 
  1}, {"Latvian", 1}, {"Norwegian Bokmål", 1}, {"Slovene", 
  1}, {"Telugu", 1}, {"Turkish", 1}, {"Uzbek", 1}, {"Hindi", 
  2}, {"Hungarian", 2}, {"Dutch", 3}, {"Finnish", 3}, {"Italian", 
  3}, {"Portuguese", 3}, {"Swedish", 3}, {"Chinese", 4}, {"French", 
  4}, {"Polish", 4}, {"Russian", 5}, {"Spanish; Castilian", 
  8}, {"German", 10}, {"English", 27}}
```

---

### [image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{{"Afrikaans", 1}, {"Bihari", 1}, {"Bulgarian", 1}, {"Croatian", 
  1}, {"Esperanto", 1}, {"Estonian", 1}, {"Igbo", 1}, {"Kannada", 
  1}, {"Latvian", 1}, {"Malayalam", 1}, {"Norwegian Bokmål", 
  1}, {"Norwegian Nynorsk", 1}, {"Romanian", 1}, {"Slovak", 
  1}, {"Slovene", 1}, {"Telugu", 1}, {"Turkish", 1}, {"Uzbek", 
  1}, {"Welsh", 1}, {"Wolof", 1}, {"Catalan; Valencian", 
  2}, {"Danish", 2}, {"Greek. Modern", 2}, {"Hungarian", 
  2}, {"Finnish", 3}, {"Hindi", 3}, {"Norwegian", 3}, {"Chinese", 
  4}, {"Polish", 4}, {"Japanese", 5}, {"Portuguese", 5}, {"Italian", 
  6}, {"Dutch", 7}, {"Latin", 7}, {"Russian", 7}, {"Swedish", 
  7}, {"Spanish; Castilian", 20}, {"French", 24}, {"German", 
  26}, {"English", 84}}
```

---

### [image: Mathematica graphics]

You may want to correlate these results with the ["real people" world's population](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers):

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: No one speaks English as their first language? How interesting!

Comment: @m_goldberg Our sample is still very small

Comment: It isn't clear whether or not to include one's first language in one's answers to second question.

Comment: @m_goldberg You're right. Edited asking to include also the first language

Comment: Is this a ploy to weed out the monoglots amongst the group?

Comment: @bobthechemist :)

Comment: The fonts on the last two diagrams are tiny :(

Comment: @YvesKlett Better now?

Answer (score 7):

Some additional statistics:

[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Where in the world could you find users?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Number of users per country:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

How many users are in countries where the ["Official Language"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/43792/193) is different from his/her first language?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: very nice. I presume the timezone and location data from the user ids?...i guess you can add {long,lat,tz}={153,-27.5,+10}...

Comment: @ubpdqn I didn't know that when I posted the poll, but it reports the IPs (in a _very_ awkward format, though). The rest is easy to get from there.

Comment: @belisarius I deleted a comment that in my mind was reflective as I thought it might have been ambiguously perceived. I think these analytics are interesting (with sampling issues acknowledged) and you are publicly sharing them for all.

Comment: @m_goldberg Take a look now

Comment: I feel that my IP has been used.., don't know why. mhmm :D

Comment: @Öskå If you really feel bad about that please refer to the edit I've done in the question. But I guess the usage is anonymous enough to be on the safe side ;)

Comment: I just saw the edit & I don't mind of course :) Waldo is here to protect us anyway.

Comment: I never knew that survey monkey collected _and_ provided the IP to poll creators. I suppose it is useful for fraud prevention, but that is probably something that needs to be done by the software. If you were also a moderator, you would easily be able to match a user with a response with the IP information from both data sets...

Comment: @rm-rf I didn't know either. In addition, the platform really sucks. I think we need a better one for the next poll.

Comment: @belisarius Ok, I can make something for that and run it on my app server. I need to first learn some SQL sanitization techniques :)

Comment: @rm-rf of course, [BobbyTables](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: @belisarius nice 'heat' map of world...look forward to more polls... καληνύχτα